# Will having stayed 170 days on a B-2 visa be an issue for a further entry?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, b1-b2-visas

I have a B-1/B-2 visa and traveled in the USA for 170 days in 2016. I did not do any work then, just enjoyed my life.

If I want to enter again in 2018 for one month, will there be any issue raised by CPB officer?

Do I have to document where I stayed last time?

When I enter again, should I have an itinerary showing where I plan to stay?

Comment: This question is very unclear, can you fix formatting and specify what is your question? And what is your nationality?

Comment: alok, I made some extensive edits, and i'm not sure I understood the last few sentences correctly. Please feel free to re-edit of roll back the changes.

Answer (score 4):

A rough "rule of thumb" is to expect trouble if trying to spend more time in USA than out, even if there are no other issues whatsoever. In your case almost a full six months last year is very close to your maximum allowed at one visit but since planning to have a gap of at least twelve months the "rule of thumb" should not be an issue.

However since six months at one time is not what a conventional tourist can afford in the way of time off work, you can expect to be questioned about it. Then if you have evidence you were vacationing rather than working it may be advisable to have that to hand when next you apply for entry. Maybe the ticket stubs for concerts, a travel diary, photographs of you at landmarks around the country ...

And an itinerary (not necessarily reservations) for next time should help too.